# How to ensure malloc is not linked in the project? ARM GCC

Tags: c, gcc, linker, arm

ARM GCC 12 version - how to ensure that `malloc` and `free` functions don't get linked by the linker and throw a *build* error if called?

Looking for similar to `delete` in C++, that is used to make sure function is not included (like hidden copy/move constructors, for instance).

Comment: Do you want to hide `malloc`/`free` only for compiled sources and static libraries or for usage from dynamically linked libraries at runtime too?

Comment: @dimich he is always very imprecise in his questions, but he usually asks about baremetal uC stuff. So I do not think that dynamic linking needs to be considered

Comment: *"functions don't get linked by the linker and throw a compilation error if called?"* -

Contraverting requirements. If the compiler throws an **error** then nothing will be linked as it will stop the build process.

Comment: @0___________ The point is that `malloc()` may be implicitly used by other C library functions, e.g. `strdup()` or stdio. Do author want to avoid these functions call at all or from compiled code only? Robust solution is not to link C library. Method to check if functions are not used may be to generate map file during linkage and analyze it. But it's not what author is asking. Other solutions depend on how exactly `malloc`/`free` are implemented for target: shared library, static library, macros...

Comment: @dimich I understand the reason.

Comment: @tilz0R is it a uC programm. Because it is going to be more complicated if you want to use dynamic linking

Comment: @tilz0R be nicer as people here are sacrificing their free time to help you. Do not be aggressive - posts like this with "period" will not help you at all. You are **asking us** for help and we are good samaritans who do it for absolutely **free**. Do not behave like a "boss". I will give a solution, but next time I will bear myself from helping you.

Comment: @0___________ thanks. Your comment proves that people on SO often get triggered to correct picky mistakes from others, instead of focusing to help them (which is the purpose of SO). Which is good because your answer doesnt stay unanswered. Ypur ajswer is more than fair with linker.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> functions don't get linked by the linker and throw a compilation error
> if called?

Contraverting requirements. If the compiler throws an **error** then nothing will be linked as it will stop the build process.

Add to the linker script:

```
PROVIDE(malloc = 0);
ASSERT(!malloc, "MALLOC PRESENT - ALERT!!!");
```

same for other symbols you want to be warned about (actually linking will terminate)